# IIS backup physical path

Tags: iis, windows-server-2016

I am new to IIS and currently doing a lab on company.

So I have 2 volumes, each stored the same html files that use to display the IIS web.

Is there a way to set my physical path to point up to both of their directory? Just in case if one volume down, the other still up and keep the web alive?

If no then is there anyway for me to achieve this?

Comment: It could be a little off-topic here. Try server fault SE.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it is impossible to do failover between two different physical paths in IIS.

If you have multiple servers. You could build ARR load balancer and specify the path that you want to do failover. Then if one server break down, ARR will mark it as unhealthy due to health test and request will be routed to another server with different path.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/configuring-application-request-routing-arr/http-load-balancing-using-application-request-routing